# Torsion Subgroup of Mapping class group.

Tags: geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, teichmueller-theory

> What is the cardinality of finite order elements in Mapping class
>   group of a surface $S_{g,n}$ of genus g and n boundary components.

1) If it is infinite then how can I generate a collection of finite order elements?

2)I know that any finite subgroup is of cardinality at most $84(g-1)$ and I also know that there are finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroup. But what about the number of subgroups in each conjugacy class?

Comment: I am very rusty on this, but if I recall correctly $S_{g, 0}$ has only finitely many conjugacy classes of finite elements, but infinitely many such elements. For example, my memory tells me that that $S_{1, 0}$ has mapping class group isomorphic to $\operatorname{Out}(F_2)\cong D_3\ast_{C_2}D_4$.

Answer (score 4):

Every conjugacy class in the mapping class group (except for the identity) is infinite. Another way of saying this is that for every element of the mapping class group (except for the identity), its centralizer has infinite index. The proof is simple, because it is not too hard to construct a pseudo-Anosov mapping class $\psi \in MCG(S_{g,n})$ such that the infinite cyclic group $\langle \psi \rangle$ is malnormal---the intersection of $\langle \psi \rangle$ and $\phi \langle \psi \rangle \phi^{-1}$ is trivial for each $\phi \not\in \langle \psi \rangle$. Once you have $\psi$, it follows that for any $\phi \in MCG(S_{g,n}) - \langle \psi \rangle$, such as any finite order element except the identity, the elements of $\langle \psi \rangle$ are all in different cosets of the centralizer of $\phi$.